# MacBook OS X 10.8.2 ant unable to find custom environment variables

Tags: ant, environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion

When I run targets on ant it says it is unable to locate the variable I passed to it.

Config for environment variables :

in build.xml

`<property environment="Env"/>`

but I am unable to find the parameter defined parameter with 
`${Env.CATALINA_HOME}`

where in the .bash_profile

`export CATALINA_HOME=/Users/olgunkaya/development/apache-tomcat-7.0.34`
and `export PATH=${PATH}:$CATALINA_HOME`

What can I do to achive this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you run `ant`, check to see if `CATALINA_HOME` is actually defined as an environment variable. I bet you'll find it isn't. Ant doesn't read your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` before starting, so if it's not already defined in your environment, Ant won't see it.

As you've seen opening a terminal window on a Mac doesn't necessarily guarantee that the `.bash_profile` file is executed. Try setting up these environment variables in `.bashrc` file instead.

Or, you can *force* `.bash_profile` to run by setting it as the Startup file in Terminal.  Select *File->Preferences* from the menu, go to the *Shell* tab, select your default shell, and then click the *Run Command* checkbox and put `.bash_profile` in there. That will guarantee that `.bash_profile` is executed with each new terminal window.

Comment: I realized that your comment is correct after some search. But couldn't make to come here to write the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when referencing a custom variable, which was definitely defined in the shell spawning `ant`.

The solution was to `EXPORT` the variable when defined (in `~/.profile`), so the shell would pass it to its children.

Comment: This question was the first I found while Googling the problem, so I thought I'd share it.